# How to create a SwiftUI button that changes opacity and triggers button action when touched?

Tags: swiftui

I wanna create a button with SwiftUI that fires the moment my finger touches it (like UIKit's touch down instead of touch up inside). I also want the opacity of the button to become 0.7 when my finger is pressing the button. And I want the opacity of the button to change back to 1 ONLY when my finger is no longer touching the button.

I've tried 2 different types of button styles to create such a button but both of them failed:

```
    struct ContentView: View {  
        var body: some View {  
            Button(action: {  
                print("action triggered")  
            }){  
                Text("Button").padding()  
            }  
                .buttonStyle(SomeButtonStyle())  
        }  
    }  

    struct SomeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {  
        func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {  
            configuration.label  
                .background(Color.green)  
                .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.7 : 1)  
                .onLongPressGesture(  
                    minimumDuration: 0,  
                    perform: configuration.trigger//Value of type 'SomeButtonStyle.Configuration' (aka 'ButtonStyleConfiguration') has no member 'trigger'  
                )  
        }  
    }  

    struct SomePrimativeButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {  
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {  
          configuration.label  
            .background(Color.green)  
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.7 : 1)//Value of type 'SomePrimativeButtonStyle.Configuration' (aka 'PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration') has no member 'isPressed'  
            .onLongPressGesture(  
              minimumDuration: 0,  
              perform: configuration.trigger  
            )  
        }  
    }
```

Apparently none of the button styles above worked because ButtonStyle and PrimitiveButtonStyle don't share the same methods and properties so I can't use both the isPressed property (which belongs to ButtonStyle) AND the trigger method (which belongs to PrimitiveButtonStyle) in the same button style.

How should I configure my button style to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I understand that author wants to see solution only with `Button`, so I dig a little more. And found something interesting at [Swift UI Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com/custom-styling/). The idea is the same as [in my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606458/9982386): use `@GestureState` and create `LongPressGesture` which `.updating($...)` this state. But in `PrimitiveButtonStyle` you don't need to compose a few gestures together. So, I simplified code a little and tested it at simulator. And I think now it just what author need:

```swift
struct ComposingGestures: View {

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            print("action triggered")
        }){
            Text("Button")
                .padding()
        }
            .buttonStyle(MyPrimitiveButtonStyle())

    }

}

struct MyPrimitiveButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: PrimitiveButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        MyButton(configuration: configuration)
    }

    struct MyButton: View {
        @GestureState private var pressed = false

        let configuration: PrimitiveButtonStyle.Configuration
        let color: Color = .green

        @State private var didTriggered = false

        var body: some View {
            // you can set minimumDuration to Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude if you think that
            // user can hold button for such a long time
            let longPress = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 300, maximumDistance: 300.0)
                .updating($pressed) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value
                    self.configuration.trigger()
            }

            return configuration.label
                .background(Color.green)
                .opacity(pressed ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                .gesture(longPress)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with `ButtonStyle`, but tried to solve it with [Composing SwiftUI Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures/composing_swiftui_gestures). I compose `TapGesture` and `LongPressGesture` and playing with `@GestureState` to control `.opacity` of "button" (which is just `Text`). The result is just as you asked:

```swift
struct ComposingGestures: View {

    enum TapAndLongPress {
        case inactive
        case pressing

        var isPressing: Bool {
            return self == .pressing
        }

    }

    @GestureState var gestureState = TapAndLongPress.inactive
    @State private var didPress = false

    var body: some View {

        let tapAndLongPressGesture = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2) // if minimumDuration <= 1 gesture state returns to inactive in 1 second
            .sequenced(before: TapGesture())
            .updating($gestureState) { value, state, transaction in
                switch value {
                case .first(true), .second(true, nil):
                    self.didPress = true // simulation of firing action
                    state = .pressing
                default:
                    state = .pressing
                }
        }

        return VStack {
            Text("action was fired!")
                .opacity(didPress ? 1 : 0)

            Text("Hello world!")
                .gesture(tapAndLongPressGesture)
                .background(Color.green)
                .opacity(gestureState.isPressing ? 0.7 : 1)
        }

    }
}
```

**P.S.** I played only with `@State var didPress` to show, how to fire action. Maybe it's better to fire it only in the first case, like this:

```swift
// ...
            .updating($gestureState) { value, state, transaction in
                switch value {
                case .first(true):
                    self.didPress = true // simulation of firing action
                    state = .pressing
                case .second(true, nil):
                    state = .pressing
                default:
                    state = .pressing
                }
```

**UPDATE**
tried code at simulator and fixed two mistakes:

```swift
// ...
    let tapAndLongPressGesture = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 300, maximumDistance: 300) // now button don't return opacity to 1 even if you move your finger
// ...
    case .first(true), .second(true, nil):
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // now there are no purple mistakes
            self.didPress = true // simulation of firing action
        }
        state = .pressing
// ...
```

Comment: Ran this in XCode but it says "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior." I also don't see the "action was fired" text label when I press "Hello world!".

Comment: And if you press "Hello world" long enough, its opacity actually goes back to 1 while the finger is still pressing the button.

Comment: @SmoothPoop69 what version of Xcode? something new, do you try it at canvas or at real device?

Comment: @SmoothPoop69 I tried to run in simulator and had same issues. check **UPDATE** in edited answer: now it works.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the update. I really appreciate it. It doesn't show the purple error anymore. But I'm wondering if it's possible to use an actual button instead of using a text label as a button. I wanna actually trigger a method when I tap the button, a simple print method will do for simplicity sake. I wonder if that's possible with SwiftUI at the moment